# jQuery fullcalendar: Fadeout deleted Event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Heyhou,

I want to fadeOut the "eventbar" in the calendar I have deleted. What should I do?

```
 eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
     // $(this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000); <- ???
     $('#kal').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent.id);
 }
```

Thanks for ur answers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know fullcalander but I do know a little jQuery.
Could it be you want something like this:

```
 eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
     $(this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000, function() {
         $('#kal').fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEvent.id);
     });
 }
```

I don't think $(this) is right, I guess you need some sort of reference to the eventbar. (like a class or id)